# How to append word count of file to file without adding the total

Tags: bash, shell-script, wc

I am running a bash script where I am appending the line count of the arguments, which are files, to another file. It does it correctly, but I keep getting a line that says "total X", X being the sum of all the line counts added together. How do I add an argument to only append the total if the # of arguments is above some number, X?
This is what I currently have:

```
wc -l $@ >> $1
```

Comment: `count=$(tail -1 $1) ; if [ $count -gt X ] ; then .... ; fi`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can suppress the total in the multi-argument form.

The simplest way I can think of is to stick to the one-argument form, when needed:

```
if [ "$#" -lt 5 ]
then
    for f in "$@"; do wc -l -- "$f"; done >>"$1"
else
    wc -l "$@" >> "$1"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Strip off the last line from the `wc` output if there are too few lines for you to want a grand total.

```
word_counts=$(wc -l -- "$@")
newline='
'
if [ "$#" -le 9 ]; then
  word_count=${word_count%"$newline"*}
fi
printf '%s\n' "$word_count" >>"$1"
```

Note the double quotes in `"$@"` and around other variable substitutions, without this your script would break on file names containing whitespace (and some other special characters) with absolutely no redeeming benefit. Note also `--` in `wc -l -- "$@"`, in case a file name starts with a `-` (without `--`, `wc` would interpret that file name as an option).